# Grid.js error seen in tests but not full application

Tags: gridjs

I'm hoping you can help me figure out a puzzling error I see when testing. I should preface this question with the fact I'm not the worlds greatest js dev.

I've created an application using the react version of Grid.js, gridjs-react, and all is well. However when I write tests I get a lot of error messages with the following

'[Error: [Grid.js] [ERROR]: Container element cannot be null]'.

I cant quite figure out why. The errors don't actually cause the tests to fail. I am testing the components that use grid.js in isolation so must be missing some sort of wrapper. Any help gratefully received!

Comment: if you can post you're code i'll be helpfull.